# Scala trying to extract value from udt (array) within a dataframe

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, extract

This seems like it should be a simple question, but I can't find anything which will work in the documentation or here in stackoverflow.

I am trying to extract a value from a udt within a dataframe within inherited Scala code. My goal is to have a `DataFrame` with a column for fit which is extracted from `yProbability.values(1)` (or whatever the correct syntax in Scala is)

The DataFrame has the following structure:

```
outputDataAAL:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 - info_conversationid:string 
 - document:string 
 - yProbability:udt
 - yHat:double
```

With an example element of yProbability being:

```
array
 - 0: 1
 - 1: 2
 - 2: []
 - 3:
     - 0: 0.8054468196483193
     - 1: 0.19455318035168068
```

In r I do a simple:

```
outputDataAAL$fit <- outputDataAAL$yProbability %>% lapply(function(x) {x[[2]][2]}) %>% unlist
```

It's easy, but slow for the data sizes I'm looking at.  This is why I would like to do it in Scala.

I have tried extracting just values (which is array element #3 within yProbability), but both of these following methods give me the error below.

```scala
val newSample = outputDataAAL.select("yProbability.values(1)")
val newSample = outputDataAAL.select($"yProbability".getItem("values(1)"))
```

The error:

```
Can't extract value from yProbability#4404: need struct type but got 
struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>
```

I've also tried to sample outputDataAAL at the `#4404` threw me off and I didn't know if it was due to a bad column.  Obviously, no luck.

Thank you very much for your help.

-Rick

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out a solution, but it is a bit ugly. I feel that there should be a simpler answer, but this works.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.ml._
val vecToArray = udf( (xs: linalg.Vector) => xs.toArray )  
val newSample = outputDataAAL.withColumn("yProbabilityArr" , vecToArray($"yProbability") )
val outputDataAALNew = newSample.withColumn("fit", $"yProbabilityArr".getItem(1))
```